# debian route all http traffic through squid

Tags: networking, debian, proxy, squid

I have a really simple Q. I just need to know how to specify an http proxy (with login credentials) within debian. The squid server is a separate machine,  and since the proxy got implemented our web services and backups on the dev server arn't working. so basically i just need to specify an http proxy within debian...

Answer (score 3):

You may want to  can create an environnement variable 'http_proxy' throught your .bashrc script and assign it the value like:

```
export http_proxy=http://login:pass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3128
```

There's also manual settings to to with the web browser but for apt-get edit your /etc/apt/apt.conf and add:

```
use Acquire::http::Proxy "http://login:pass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3128";
```

EDIT:
You may wish to look at the following article to setup iptables tor edirect the traffic to your proxy:
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html

Comment: what if nobody logs in? I need it to be as transparent as possible, this is our web dev server, most users don't login they just access shares via samba..

Comment: I suspect i need to use iptables?

Comment: http_port xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3128 transparent, add this in squid.conf

Answer (score 3):

**Transparent http traffic routing**

```
# Your debian machine (gateway)
LAN_IP="192.168.0.1"

# Your network
LAN_IP_RANGE="192.168.0.0/24"                                                               

# Your squid machine
PROXY_IP="192.168.0.254"                                                                   
PROXY_PORT="3128"

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s $LAN_IP_RANGE ! -d $LAN_IP_RANGE -p TCP --destination-port 80 -j MARK --set-mark 11                                     
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark 11 -p TCP -j DNAT --to-destination ${PROXY_IP}:${PROXY_PORT}                                                          
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 11 -p TCP -j SNAT --to-source $LAN_IP
```

Answer (score 2):

Transparent proxying CANNOT be done with login credentials. Think about it; if the user doesn't know it's going on, then you can't expect them to engage in a username/password exchange!

Answer (score 0):

Hi This may help you. Try this.

Add this in /etc/squid.conf

auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/getpwnam_auth /etc/passwd
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid Proxy Cacheing Server
auth_param basic creddentialsttl 1 hour

I have also been advised to enter the acl:

acl password proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow password

One site has stated that you need the entry:

authentication_program /usr/lib/squid/getpwnam_auth